# Count number of days between two dates including start and end date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to have a formula similar to `networkdays`, but I don't want it to count only work days.

For example: March 23, 2015 thru March 28, 2015

Those days are Monday thru Saturday, if I use networkdays, I get a result of 5, I want the result to be the number of days to include week days, so in this example, 6.

I have tried datedif, days, and networkdays. I tried doing cell1-cell2+1, which always gives me the right answer UNLESS there is no data in cell1 or cell2.

Comment: What data might be in cell1 and cell2 if there are not dates there? Would they be blank, or have some other data type in them?

Comment: They would be blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you have to check for is blank cells you can use the following formula:

```
=IF(NOT(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1))),A1-B1+1,"")
```

The formula reads: if neither of these cells is blank use the formula, otherwise show an empty string.

This can be improved in two ways to check for negative number results.

1. `=IF(NOT(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1))),MAX(A1:B1)-MIN(A1:B1)+1,"")` which handles either order
2. `=IF(AND(NOT(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1))),A1>B1),A1-B1+1,"")` which only shows results for positive numbers

Alternatively there is a VBA function that can be found called `isDate()`.

Comment: Sir, thank you! That solved the problem beautifully. I'm not ready for VBA yet.

Comment: I tried to vote you up, but I don't have the street cred (I mean reputation) to do so. I did mark your answer as the best!! Thanks again.